# Capture input from MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue I can't get my head around.

I have an userform where I have `MsgBox` telling the user if some boxes is missing information, and then asking of they want to continue.

When they user presses `Yes`, the values  of the userform are transferred into the sheet as it should. But when the user chooses no, the values are still transferred...

How to make the `MsgBox` close, when user chooses `No`, without the values getting transferred?

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: Here is [Microsoft documentation for the msgbox function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Ret = MsgBox("Blah Blah", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

    If Ret = vbYes Then
        MsgBox "You pressed `Yes`" '<~~ Code to transfer to the sheet here
    ElseIf Ret = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "You pressed `No`"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the records onto the sheet only when the user clicks on "Yes" in the msgbox window, you may try something like this...

Replace the msgbox as per your requirement.

```
Dim Ans As Long
Ans = MsgBox("You didn't fill all the information." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm Please!")
If Ans = vbYes Then
    'Code to submit the records onto the Sheet
End If
```